# git update a branch with the exact contents of another without losing history

Tags: git

I want to be able to update a branch with the exact files from another branch without losing history on that branch (eg not `push --force`). The scenario is a branch tracking deployments to an environment (i don't want to lose history of previous deployments).

I can do this by copying the files in the branch I want to load to a temp folder and then deleting everything in the deployment branch and replacing with the new files but this seems very un-git and I'm sure there would be a better way.

```
git checkout a
rsync -av . /tmp/repo --exclude .git
git checkout deploy
git rm -rf .
rsync -av /tmp/repo/ .
git add .
git commit -m 'deployed'
```

**Is there a more efficient git method to do this?**

Example:

Initial state

```
deploy:
   - b.txt
   - readme.md
 log:
     another-deploy

a:
   - a.txt
   - readme.md
 log:
     whatever
```

final state

```
deploy:
   - a.txt
   - readme.md
 log:
   deployed
   another-deploy

a:
   - a.txt
   - readme.md
 log:
     whatever
```

Comment: Create a new temp branch `x` at `a`. Rebase `x` onto `deploy`. Delete `x`. Is this close?

Comment: @paulhicks I don't think that will work. It may leave extra files in the deploy branch that aren't in a, it will also likely have merge conflicts.

Comment: Not merge. Rebase. If you don't ff deploy, won't affect that branch at all.

Comment: It will convert each `a` commit to a diff and apply it on top of `deploy` (without changing `deploy`). Then you can make the new last child commit `a`. And leave `deploy` alone.

Comment: @PaulHicks I've added an example, I think if i rebase it will get other commits in the history for the deploy branch. It also wont remove any files which were not in the ancestry of a (eg b.txt)

Comment: Yes, the example is very good. I'll think about it.

Comment: This isn't really git's job, since there's (potentially) no common history.  Your solution looks better than what git supports. In theory, the solution would be to checkout `deploy`, apply reverse diffs back to the most recent common commit, apply `a`s diffs from there, and squash-merge your new HEAD with `deploy`.

Comment: @PaulHicks fair enough, ill go with what I have then